# Visual Studio 2015 Build Tools / CPP Runtime v140 Dockerfile isn't working correctly

Tags: c++, visual-studio, docker, dockerfile

I have been trying to set up a Dockerfile to run a project developed in Visual Studio 2015 on CPP Runtime v140 for a week or two now (specifically, [this](https://github.com/aacitelli/OASIS_FeatureRecognition) one, where I essentially just `docker cp` it in and then `msbuild` the solution file) and I keep running into issues.

Here is my current Dockerfile:

```
# escape=`

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019

# Restore the default Windows shell for correct batch processing.
SHELL ["cmd", "/S", "/C"]

# Install Visual Studio 2015 Build Tools
ADD https://download.microsoft.com/download/E/E/D/EEDF18A8-4AED-4CE0-BEBE-70A83094FC5A/BuildTools_Full.exe C:\TEMP\vs_buildtools.exe
RUN C:\TEMP\vs_buildtools.exe `
    --quiet --norestart --nocache --wait `
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VCTools --includeRecommended`
    --add Microsoft.Component.MSBuild

# Install C++ Runtime v140
ADD https://download.microsoft.com/download/6/A/A/6AA4EDFF-645B-48C5-81CC-ED5963AEAD48/vc_redist.x64.exe C:\TEMP\cpp_runtime.exe
RUN C:\TEMP\cpp_runtime.exe /quiet /install

# Define the entry point for the docker container.
ENTRYPOINT ["cmd.exe"]
```

This one hangs prohibitively long (20+ minutes, if not forever) on step 4/7, running vs_buildtools.exe. If I simply do the ADD commands and then run them while in the container itself, they always just finish instantly and don't actually change the file system.

I have been able to get Visual Studio 2015 build tools installed correctly before, but it gives me an error about `Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props` not being found (similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41695251/c-microsoft-cpp-default-props-was-not-found) StackOverflow question). It is looking for these in the v160 place, not the v140 as I'd want it to.

Can anyone spot something wrong with my Dockerfile, or suggest a better way to go about accomplishing this? I've tried many different things. I am fairly new to Docker, so maybe there is just some fundamental misunderstanding on my part. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I abandoned the approach of manually downloading the Build Tools + CPP Runtime, and instead used Chocolatey to get it set up. I'd previously tried it, but unbeknownst to me, internet inside Windows containers was broken then, so I fixed that (required a little bit of [Hyper-V NAT Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54762593/docker-hyper-v-was-unable-to-find-a-virtual-switch-with-name-dockernat#:%7E:text=open%20the%20hyper%2Dv%20manger,to%20create%20it%20directly%20there%20.), and [a powershell command](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/2760#issuecomment-430889666), though both may not be necessary) and then Chocolatey worked perfectly for my use case and allowed me to compile the project.

Here's the dockerfile:

```
# escape=`

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019

# Interpret as Powershell
# SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'Continue'; $verbosePreference='Continue';"]

# Install chocolatey
ADD https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1 C:\install.ps1
RUN @powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "iex C:\install.ps1" 

# Install Visual C++ Build Tools, as per: https://chocolatey.org/packages/visualcpp-build-tools
RUN choco install visualcpp-build-tools -version 14.0.25420.1 -y

# Add msbuild to PATH
RUN setx /M PATH "%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin"

# Test msbuild can be accessed without path
RUN msbuild -version

CMD [ "cmd.exe" ]
```

Comment: Strangly, but same setup fails as of 2022, probably due to changes made for ltsc2019 since then.