# Nested virtualization in Azure

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, virtualization

I am trying to run Docker Desktop in an Azure VM. The Azure VM has Windows 10 Pro as the OS.

So, I am following this [Azure document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/nested-virtualization)

In the step **Configure Nested Virtualization**, I am running the below command after updating the VM name. I ma executing as PowerShell script under **Run command** pane.

```
Set-VMProcessor -VMName <VMName> -ExposeVirtualizationExtensions $true
```

I am getting the following error.

```
Set-VMProcessor : Hyper-V was unable to find a virtual machine with name
```

I have noticed that documentation mentions executing it when the system is in the OFF state.
While in the **Run Command** pane, it is not letting to execute the command if the machine is in the OFF state.

What I am doing wrong?

The VM is of type **Standard D4as v4**

Answer (score 0):

To Enable Nested virtualization in Azure, Make use of below command:

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All -NoRestart
Install -WindowsFeature RSAT-Hyper-V-Tools -IncludeAllSubFeature
```

[image]

Enable Hyper-V with PowerShell and DISM:

```
DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /All /FeatureName:Microsoft-Hyper-V
```

[image]

Now, when I tried the same command, I got the same error like below:

```
Set-VMProcessor -VMName <VMName> -ExposeVirtualizationExtensions $true
```

[image]

Make sure you have correctly replaced **`VMName`**  with the actual name of your Azure VM in the command. You can check the name of your VM in the Azure portal or by running the following command **`Get-AzVM`** like below:

Go to Server manager -> Tools -> Hyper-V manager -> VM you can see the name of the virtual machine that you want to enable nested virtualization.

Run the `Set-VMProcessor` command with the `-VMName` parameter set to the name of the virtual machine got result successfully like below:

```
Set-VMProcessor -VMName <VMName> -ExposeVirtualizationExtensions $true
```

[image]

***Reference***:

[windows - Docker : Hyper-V was unable to find a virtual switch with name "DockerNAT" - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54762593/docker-hyper-v-was-unable-to-find-a-virtual-switch-with-name-dockernat) by leopal

Answer (score 0):

After some initial issues, I was able to get Docker working on a Windows 11 Azure VM with the following steps:

1. Ensure your Azure VM supports nested virtualization AND uses the standard security setting - at the moment, the default trusted launch security setting is not compatible with nested virtualization
2. Check WSL is working correctly and install a Linux distro if there is not one installed, for example: `wsl.exe --install "Ubuntu-20.04"`
3. Enable nested virtualization following these instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/lab-services/how-to-enable-nested-virtualization-template-vm-using-script?tabs=powershell#prerequisites
4. Download docker and it should now work